# How to show my own context menu in Internet Explorer

Tags: c++, winapi, internet-explorer, contextmenu, bho

I'm writing add-on for Internet Explorer 9 and I have to change default context menu to my own. I'm writing a BHO in C++ and I'm using ATL. I managed to handle event of showing context menu ([HTMLDocumentEvents2::oncontextmenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), but I can't display my own one. Here is the code fired when you click right mouse button:

```
VARIANT_BOOL STDMETHODCALLTYPE CSpellCheckerBHO::OnContextMenu( IHTMLEventObj *pEvtObj)
{
    HMENU contextMenu = CreatePopupMenu();

    MENUITEMINFO item_info = { 0 };
    item_info.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
    item_info.fMask = MIIM_TYPE | MIIM_ID;
    item_info.fType = MFT_STRING;
    item_info.wID = 0;
    item_info.dwTypeData = L"TEST";
    item_info.cch = 4;

    BOOL result = InsertMenuItem(contextMenu, 0, FALSE, &item_info);
    HWND browserHandle = 0;
    HRESULT hr = _webBrowser->get_HWND((LONG_PTR*)&browserHandle);

    result = TrackPopupMenuEx(contextMenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, 0,0, browserHandle , NULL);

    return VARIANT_FALSE;
}
```

_webBrowser is a pointer to IWebBrowser2 object, I got it from SetSite function.

The standard context menu is not displayed (due to returning VARIANT_FALSE), but TrackPopupMenuEx does nothing and returns 0.

Do you know what I am doing wrong? I need simple menu with some text items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fgured it out. Igor Tandetnik helped me on [IE addon forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/2a21656a-10ff-48f3-aa77-a26d27347a8e/). HWND was from different proccess and `TrackPopupMenuEx` expects HWND belonging to the calling thread. Here's the code that works:

```
VARIANT_BOOL STDMETHODCALLTYPE CSpellCheckerBHO::OnContextMenu( IHTMLEventObj *pEvtObj)
{
    HMENU contextMenu = CreatePopupMenu();

    MENUITEMINFO item_info = { 0 };
    item_info.cbSize = sizeof(MENUITEMINFO);
    item_info.fMask = MIIM_ID | MIIM_STRING;
    item_info.wID = 0;
    item_info.dwTypeData = L"TEST";
    item_info.cch = 4;

    BOOL result = InsertMenuItem(contextMenu, 0, TRUE, &item_info);

    CComPtr<IDispatch> dispDoc;
    _webBrowser->get_Document(&dispDoc);
    CComQIPtr<IOleWindow> oleWindow = dispDoc;
    HWND browserHandle;
    oleWindow->GetWindow(&browserHandle);


    CComQIPtr<IHTMLEventObj2> htmlEventObj = pEvtObj;
    long x, y;
    htmlEventObj->get_screenX(&x);
    htmlEventObj->get_screenY(&y);  

    result = TrackPopupMenuEx(contextMenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, x, y, browserHandle , NULL);

    return VARIANT_FALSE;
}
```